# How to Get Current User Name?

Tags: lotusscript

i have a problem like this
i have two text boxes(A,B) which i have selected as " Computed when Composed "
when 'A' Login then in Text A Current User Login Name Should come automatically,
if 'B' Login then 'B' user name should come automatically in 'B' Text and it should be saved when i submit the form to the next level
how to do this ?

Regards
Smitha

Answer (score 1):

There is the following example  [here](http://www.notes411.com/dominosource/faq.nsf/0/41B26D5E251DBA9D80256D6E007AC1C0!OpenDocument) :

*You can use this to get the current web user's Domino user name:*

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim username As String
username = session.EffectiveUserName
```

***You do have to have the 'Run Agent As Web User' agent property checked for this to work.***

Comment: In my quick tests, you *don't* need to have "Run as Web User" checked.

Answer (score 1):

If using an AJAX call you can also do:

```
Dim session as new notessession
Dim request as notesdocument

set request = session.documentcontext
Msgbox request.remote_user(0) ' returns the name of the current user
```

I am not 100% sure if this works with WebQuerySave or WebQueryOpen agents but it should

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the @UserName to get the current user name.